# How to install REVtex into TEXlive

Tags: texlive, revtex, scripts

I have downloaded and installed TEXlive, I now wish to use REVtex on it. I have downloaded the zip file revtex4-1. However I do not know how to install it. I have looked on other forums and they have mentioned 'shell' and 'command prompt' but I do not know what that means.

Comment: What exactly did you install? I have TeXLive installed, `revtex4-1` is already installed by TeXLive. No need to do anything manually

Comment: I have the most recent TeXLive. How do you access revtex4-1in TeXLive?

Comment: you should have it already just use `\documentclass{revtex4-1}` as usual. If you installed a subset of texlive and need it adding use `tlmgr install revtex`

Comment: Any updates here?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem under linux (Ubuntu). I found `revtex` in package `texlive-publishers`. Try:

```
sudo apt install texlive-publishers
```

Comment: Maybe it can be useful to install `texlive-publishers-doc` too.